# Rails Dynamic Finders Return nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, null, dynamic-finders

Using Ruby on Rails - sqlite3, rails 3.2.2, ruby 1.9.3p125 (on windows XP)

Having the record in the db:

```
Shop.find(123) - returns the shop
Shop.where(:id => 123) - returns the shop
```

but

```
Shop.find_by_id(123) returns nil
Shop.find_by_name("some_name") returns nil
```

So do all the dynamic finders (notice it  returns nil for integer value and for string values)

Why aren't they defined?

Comment: thats weird. posting your model could help

Comment: Any model, in any app... Since day one. Could it be one of the gems?

Comment: um try upgrading rails to 3.2.6